# How to reshape pandas DataFrame, transforming column names to values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, reshape

I have this matrix:

```
       columnA columnB ... columnX
index0 val0A   val0B   ... val0X
index1 val1A   val1B   ... val1X
...    ...     ...     ... ...
indexN valNA   valNB   ... valNX
```

I want to reshape the pandas DataFrame in this way:

```
       values  columns
index0A val0A   columnA
index1A val1A   columnA
...     ...     ...     
index0B val0B   columnB
index1B val1B   columnB
...
indexNX valNX   columnX
```

How can I achieve it and what is the usual name for this transformation?

Comment: Take a look at ```stack()```

Comment: Note that `stack` will give you a multi-index which may not be desirable in this case.

Comment: `stack` in combination with `reset_index` will do the trick.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you want melt()

An example

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [10,20,45,34,23], "B": [20, 30, 10, 40, 50]})
df

    A   B
0   10  20
1   20  30
2   45  10
3   34  40
4   23  50
```

pd.melt(df)

```
    variable    value
0   A          10
1   A          20
2   A          45
3   A          34
4   A          23
5   B          20
6   B          30
7   B          10
8   B          40
9   B          50
```

Comment: Then at the end, you can just take the `value` column, and you can set the index to whatever length `N*X` thing you want, in the event that the integers 0 through `N*X` are not the desired output index (since this is ambiguous in the OP's questions; e.g. is index `index0A` just an integer, or some new index value entirely?)

Comment: Thank you for pointing me to `melt()` - I was searching exactly for this function. Regarding the index, I reset it with `reset_index()` and I preserved it using the `id_vars` parameter in `melt()`.